# emit value from mounted in child.vue to parent.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, emit

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I need to `emit` a value to my `parent.vue` - but my code line `this.$emit('info', this.hide);` doesn't work out.

If I `console.log(this.hide)` i get my value correct in this case **false**, otherwise if my `if-statement` is correct I get it **true**.

What is the mistake in here?

script of my child.vue:

```
data(){
  return {
    hide: true,
  }
}

mounted() {
  if (statement) {
    if(some statement) {
      //do something
    } else {
      this.hide = false;
      console.log(this.hide); //HERE I GET CORRECT VALUE
      this.$emit('info', this.hide); //THIS DOESNT WORK
    }
  }
}
```

How it should work in my parent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div @info="info">
    <div> //THIS DIV SHOULD BE SHOWN IF this.hide = false
    </div>
    <div> //THIS DIV SHOULD BE SHOWN IF this.hide = true
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you have a `@info` handler inside parent.vue?

Comment: Yes.. I have @info="info" in my parent.vue

Comment: updated my question to show you what I need to do..

Comment: what is the name of your child component?

Comment: Parent: App.vue / child: login.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following snippet :

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div class="">
      child
      <button @click="changeHide">change hide</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      hide: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeHide() {
      this.hide = !this.hide
      this.sendInfo()
    },
    sendInfo() {
      this.$emit('info', this.hide);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //if (statement) {
      //if(some statement) {
        //do something
      //} else {
        this.hide = false;
        this.sendInfo()
      //}
    }
  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      info: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setInfo(val) {
      this.info = val
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="!info"> //THIS DIV SHOULD BE SHOWN IF this.hide = false
  </div>
  <div v-if="info"> //THIS DIV SHOULD BE SHOWN IF this.hide = true
  </div>
  <p>from child info is: {{ info }}</p>
  <Child @info="setInfo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally in App.vue `(Parent)`

you should have something like

```
<login @info="someHandler"></login>
```

there is no need to go for a child component if you gonna jus use to manage some logic. It is appropriate only if have some contents in the template.
Also placing emit handler on some div. Thats not how emit works

Below is a simple working example

**App.vue** (parent)

```
<template>

  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

  <Child @changeTitle="ChangeT($event)" />

</template>
<script>
import Child from "./components/Child"
export default{
name:'App',
components: {
    Child,
},
data()
{
   return{
     title:'Rick Grimes'
         }
},
methods:{
    ChangeT(title)
    {
      this.title=title;
    },
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
  <button type="button" @click='passEvent'> Update me</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name:'Child',
  methods:{
    passEvent()
    {
      this.$emit('changeTitle','Awesome ')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```